# SQL - Joining columns from the same table in a Query

Tags: sql, join, publishing, openoffice-base

SOLVED ! See the answer bellow !

Before I explain my problem I want to apologise for those who would feel this question is too long but I feel like I must give some details to make things the clearer possible. Though, the problem is simple to understand it is not that simple to me to implement.

I have 3 tables.

Hata and Icon contains images I want to link with Succes which contains texts

**[Hata]**

```
id, INTEGER, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY_KEY
hata Image
idLang, VARCHAR(5)
```

**[Icon]**

```
id, INTEGER, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY_KEY
icon, IMAGE
idPhrase, INTEGER
```

**[Succes]**

```
id, INTEGER, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY_KEY
idPhrase, INTEGER
titre, VARCHAR(25)
desc, VARCHAR(125)
idLang, VARCHAR(5)
```

Here is a sample showing how the Succes table looks like

```
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
| id | idPhrase | titre           | desc             | idLang |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  1 |        1 | Hello           | Desc in English  | en-GB  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  2 |        1 | Salut           | Desc in French   | fr-FR  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  3 |        1 | 今日は           | Desc in Japanese | ja-JP  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  4 |        2 | Goodbye         | Desc in English  | en-GB  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  5 |        2 | Au revoir       | Desc in French   | fr-FR  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  6 |        2 | またね            | Desc in Japanese | ja-JP  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  7 |        3 | You're welcome  | Desc in English  | en-GB  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  8 |        3 | Je vous en prie | Desc in French   | fr-FR  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
|  9 |        3 | どういたしまして      | Desc in Japanese | ja-JP  |
+----+----------+-----------------+------------------+--------+
...
```

The tables are now joined using this **WHERE** conditions

*Icons.idPhrase = Succes.idPhrase **AND** Hata.idLang=Succes.idLang*

Everything would be fine if there would be nothing specific in the Succes table.

In fact, for each Icon there are 3 sentences and the idPhrase links them but in the actual result set I somehow have redundancies.

```
Icon1|FlagIcon1|TitreLang1|DescLang1
Icon1|FlagIcon2|TitreLang2|DescLang2
Icon1|FlagIcon3|TitreLang3|DescLang3
Icon2|FlagIcon1|TitreLang1|DescLang1
Icon2|FlagIcon2|TitreLang2|DescLang2
Icon2|FlagIcon3|TitreLang3|DescLang3
...
```

What I'd like to achieve is the following (just the very first row):

`Icon1|FlagIcon1|TitreLang1|DescLang1|FlagIcon2|TitreLang2|DescLang2|FlagIcon3|TitreLang3|DescLang`

or
`Icon1|FlagIcon1|FlagIcon2|FlagIcon3|TitreLang1|DescLang1|TitreLang2|DescLang2|TitreLang3|DescLang3`

or even
`Icon1|FlagIcon1|FlagIcon2|FlagIcon3|TitreLang1|TitreLang2|TitreLang3|DescLang1|DescLang2|DescLang3`

In other words, it would be like I'd joined several queries together such as

```
SELECT icon FROM Icon
```

Joined with

```
SELECT Hata.hata AS fEN, Succes.titre AS tEN, Succes.desc AS dEN
FROM Hata, Succes
WHERE Hata.idLang=Succes.idLang AND Succes.idLang='en-GB'
```

Joined With

```
SELECT Hata.hata AS fFR, Succes.titre AS tFR, Succes.desc AS dFR
FROM Hata, Succes
WHERE Hata.idLang=Succes.idLang AND Succes.idLang='fr-FR'
```

And so on...
Just the problem of ensuring the links between tables (icon 1 with sentence 1)

Here's another sample on how it should (may) look like

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
| icon  | fEN   | fFR   | fJP   | tEN            | tFR              | tJA        | dEN             | dFR            | dJA              |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
| <img> | <img> | <img> | <img> | Hello          | Salut            | 今日は      | Desc in English | Desc in French | Desc in Japanese |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
| <img> | <img> | <img> | <img> | Goodbye        | Au revoir        | またね       | Desc in English | Desc in French | Desc in Japanese |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
| <img> | <img> | <img> | <img> | You're welcome | Je vous en pries | どういたしまして | Desc in English | Desc in French | Desc in Japanese |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------------+------------------+------------+-----------------+----------------+------------------+
...
```

I've browsed for SQL reference to try many things but they don't seem to do what I expect (CONCATENATE, UNION, etc...)
I also tried the following query but it gives me an error message.

```
SELECT Icon.icon, Hata.hata AS fEN,Hata.hata AS fFR,Hata.hata AS fJA
    ,'FR'.'titre', 'FR'.'desc'
    ,'JA'.'titre', 'JA'.'desc'
    ,'UK'.'titre', 'UK'.'desc'
FROM Hata, Icon
LEFT JOIN Succes AS FR ON 'FR'.'idLang' = 'Hata'.'idLang' AND 'FR'.'idLang' = 'fr-FR'
LEFT JOIN Succes AS JA ON 'JA'.'idLang' = 'Hata'.'idLang' AND 'FR'.'idLang' = 'ja-JP'
LEFT JOIN Succes AS UK ON 'UK'.'idLang' = 'Hata'.'idLang' AND 'FR'.'idLang' = 'en-GB'
```

the message is

```
Statut SQL: HY000
Error Code: 1000

syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting BETWEEN or IN or SQL_TOKEN_LIKE
```

but it seems my syntax is good according to sample I've found even on StackOverflow.
I must also specify that I'm using OpenOffice Base and my purpose is publishing a document. Maybe there is something specific to OOo such as LEFT JOIN not implemented but the code get coloured so I think it should be fine.

Thank you for your availability and help.

Comment: Have you looked at using a UNION to join multiple select queries? It may not work for all of them, but for some of those it would be a good start.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
As I wrote before I tried many things and UNION belongs to them. From what I saw **UNION does not combine columns but rows** and therefore you have to take care that datatypes for each column is the same.

Comment: To do that is easy, just return a null for select statements that won't return that column, and you can build them up.

Comment: I think I should try to use MySQL on Linux to test the queries just to see if the problem would be coming from Open Office Base or the query itself.
I don't understand the NULL thing much. If I already can't add columns with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: What I have done before is Select colA, colB, null FROM ... UNION Select null, null, colC FROM ...

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get it.
I've tried with MySQL and it does something like an exclusive join

```
mysql> SELECT titre AS tfr, titre AS ten, titre AS tjp FROM data WHERE idlang=1
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT null,titre AS ten, null FROM data WHERE idlang=2
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT null, null, titre as tjp FROM data WHERE idlang=3;
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| tfr              | ten              | tjp              |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Salut            | Salut            | Salut            |
| Au revoir        | Au revoir        | Au revoir        |
| Je vous en pries | Je vous en pries | Je vous en pries |
| NULL             | Hello            | NULL             |
| NULL             | Goodbye          | NULL             |
| NULL             | You're Welcome   | NULL             |
| NULL             | NULL             | Konnichiha       |
| NULL             | NULL             | Mata ne          |
| NULL             | NULL             | Douitashimashite |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If in the 1st SELECT I do titre AS tfr, null, null the column headers get to null.

```
mysql> SELECT titre AS tfr, titre AS ten, titre AS tjp FROM data WHERE idlang=1
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT null,titre AS ten, null FROM data WHERE idlang=2
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT null, null, titre as tjp FROM data WHERE idlang=3;
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| tfr              | NULL             | NULL             |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Salut            | NULL             | NULL             |
| Au revoir        | NULL             | NULL             |
| Je vous en pries | NULL             | NULL             |
| NULL             | Hello            | NULL             |
| NULL             | Goodbye          | NULL             |
| NULL             | You're Welcome   | NULL             |
| NULL             | NULL             | Konnichiha       |
| NULL             | NULL             | Mata ne          |
| NULL             | NULL             | Douitashimashite |
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

It still doesn't looks like the result I want.

I need to concentrate on that data table to get all in one line but I keep wondering how to achieve this. In principle it is very simple but I can't translate that in SQL.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE data;
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_phrase | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| titre     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| desc      | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idicon    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idlang    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Actually idicon is redundant with id_phrase (don't really need it so pretend it does not exist).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HERE ARE SOME PROPOSITIONS IF YOU WOULD MEET A RESEMBLING PROBLEM.

NB: The column names and table names may differ from the original question but the problem is the same.

I've been asking this question on another forum and here are 2 queries I tested and can certify are working with MySQL 5.5

Query 1 :

```
SELECT id_phrase
    , idicon
    , max(case idlang when 1 then titre end) AS tfr
    , max(case idlang when 1 then DESC  end) AS dfr
    , max(case idlang when 2 then titre end) AS ten
    , max(case idlang when 2 then DESC  end) AS den
    , max(case idlang when 3 then titre end) AS tjp
    , max(case idlang when 3 then DESC  end) AS djp
FROM DATA
    WHERE idlang IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY id_phrase, idicon
ORDER BY id_phrase ASC
```

Query 2 :

```
SELECT t1.id_phrase, t1.idicon, t1.titre AS tfr, t1.descr AS dfr, t2.titre AS ten, t2.descr AS den, t3.titre AS tjp, t3.descr AS djp
FROM DATA AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATA AS t2
    ON t1.id_phrase=t2.id_phrase
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATA AS t3
    ON t1.id_phrase=t3.id_phrase
WHERE t1.idlang=1 AND t2.idlang=2 AND t3.idlang=3
```

You're welcome if these queries may help you.

[Source](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1180425/bases-donnees/langage-sql/jointure-partir-meme-table/) (french)